# R Cat function / Input

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a Question & Answer format where that answer becomes an input for each variable. Namely, `sex` and `interest rate` here.

```
cat("Select Sex", ":M = Male, F = Female", "\n", sep=" ")
Sex <- readline("Sex = ")

cat("Input interest rate in  annual compounding basis", "\n", sep=" ")
interest.rate <- as.numeric(readline("Interest rate = "))
```

What would I have to add under each to put each answer as input?

I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: It would be one of the value for 'Sex' and interest.rate

Comment: What is the expected output? Sex variable should contain 'Sex = M' or 'Sex = F' ?

Comment: The expected output depends on the answer 'M' or 'F'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question but if I got it well you would like the inputs from `read.line` to be re-used as inputs elsewhere?

Something like that?

```
cat("Select Sex", ":M = Male, F = Female", "\n", sep=" ")
Sex <- readline("Sex = ")

cat("Input interest rate in  annual compounding basis", "\n", sep=" ")
interest.rate <- as.numeric(readline("Interest rate = "))

cat(paste0("Input values where ", Sex, " (Sex) and ", interest.rate, " (interest rate)."))
```